# Query on schema implementation in Berkeley DB

Tags: berkeley-db, berkeley-sockets

I found below parameters which our code is using, amidst schema implementation phase. We are just using the default values as shown below.

```
 enum                { CACHE_SIZE_KBYTES     = 10000,
                              LOG_SIZE_KBYTES       = 2000,
                              CHKPT_COALESCE_KBYTES = 1,
                              CHKPT_COALESCE_MINS   = 0,
                              TXN_PER_LOG_PRUNE_CHK = 50,
                              PAGE_SIZE_KBYTES      = 0,
                              MAX_LOG_FILE_NAME_LEN = 25 };
```

My question:
Can you please help me understand the significance of these above 7 parameters? so that i can know when to tune these values, as required?

Answer (score 0):

Those variables are application specific, not part of Berkeley DB.

Find how those variables are used in Berkeley DB API calls and then read the Berkeley DB documentation at oracle.com for those calls.